# How can I accelerate the generation of the an MD5 Checksum within vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, md5, checksum, hardware-acceleration

I'm working with some very large files residing on P2 (Panasonic) cards.  Part of the process we employ is to first generate a checksum of the file we are going to copy, then copy the file, then run a checksum on the file to confirm that it copied OK.    The problem is, is that files are large (70 GB+) and take a long time to complete.  It's an issue since we will eventually be dealing with thousands of these files.

I would like to find a faster way to generate the checksum other than using the System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
I don't care if this means using a specialized hardware card, provided it works and is not to ungodly expensive.  I would prefer to have a method of encoding that provided some feedback as to how far the process has gone along so I can display it like I do now.

The application is written in vb.net.  I would prefer to be able to use it as component, library, reference within my application, but I'm willing to call an outside application if there is enough improvement in the speed of generating the checksum.

Needless to say, the checksum must be consistent and correct. :-)

Thank you in advance for your time and efforts,

Richard

Comment: Is there any reason you have to compute the checksum *before* you copy the file, rather than during?

Answer (score 2):

I see one potential way to speed up this process: calculate the MD5 of the source file **while** performing the copy, not prior to it. This will reduce the number of times you'll need to read the entire file from 3 (source hash, copy, destination hash) to 2 (copy, destination hash).

The downside of this all is that you'll have to write your own copying code (as opposed to just relying on System.IO.File.Copy), and there's a non-zero chance that this will turn out to be slower in the end anyway than the 3-step process.

Other than that, I don't think there's much you can do here, as the entire process is I/O bound by design. You're spending most of your time reading/writing the file, and even at 100MB/s (a respectable I/O speed for your typical SATA drive), you'll do about 5.8GB/min at best.

With a modern processor, the overhead of calculating the MD5 (or anything else) doesn't factor into things very much, so speeding it up won't improve your overall throughput. Crypto accelerators in particular won't help you here, as unless the driver implementation is very efficient, they'll add more overhead due to context switches required to feed the data to the external card than they'll save.

What you do want to improve is the I/O speed. The .NET framework is already pretty efficient when it comes to this (using nicely-sized buffers, overlapped I/O and such), but it's possible an optimized native Windows application will perform better here. My advice: [Google around](http://www.google.com/search?q=md5+windows+command+line) for a few native MD5 calculators, and see how they compare to your current .NET implementation. If the difference in hash calculation speed is >10%, it's worth switching to using said external app.

Comment: As you mentioned, something like DeltaCopy(http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) or rsync  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is the way to go here rather than writing your own application.

Comment: Richard: to my knowledge, neither rsync nor the other package has the verify step that the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to avoid using MD5. MD5 is a cryptographic hash function, designed to provide certain cryptographic features. For merely detecting accidental corruption, it is way over-engineered and slow. There are many faster checksums, the design of which can be understood by examining the literature of error detection and correction. Some common examples are the [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) checksums, of which CRC32 is very common, but you can also relatively easily compute 64 or 128 bit or even larger CRCs much much faster than an MD5 hash.